# Java Generics error while compiling

Tags: java, generics

Example

```
    private static final Comparator<A> PRODUCT_CODE_COMPARATOR = new Comparator<A>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(final A o1, final A o2)
    {
        return o1.getCode().compareTo(o2.getCode());
    }
};
public static <T extends A> List<T> sortProductsByCode(final Collection<T> productModels)
{
    return sortProducts(productModels, PRODUCT_CODE_COMPARATOR);
}

private static <T> List<T> sortProducts(final Collection<T> t, final Comparator<T> comparator)
{
    final List<T> variants = new ArrayList<T>(t);
    Collections.sort(variants, comparator);
    return variants;
}
```

Getting an error at return sortProducts(productModels, PRODUCT_CODE_COMPARATOR);

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need your declaration of sortProducts to be:

```
private static <T> List<T> sortProducts(final Collection<T> t, 
                                        final Comparator<? super T> comparator)
```

This allows the Comparator to compare T's or any super class of T. Or, in other words, the method will accept `Comparator<T>` or `Comparator<A>`.